Vue 3 Composition API, how to modify a prop using map?
I am trying to add some more properties to each posts data object, posts also has several other fields like links that I do not need to update...
const props = defineProps({
    posts: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
    },
});

const localPosts = props.posts;

localPosts.data.map((post) => {
    return {
        ...post,
        label: 'new value here',
    };
});

It logs fine with the updated label, but causes random errors in my application, such as Unhandled error during execution of watcher callback.
If I remove the mapping, no issues.
Could someone please show me how I can receive an array of objects as a prop and add new values?

It's not clear what you want to achieve, localPosts implies you need to copy posts from the prop. You'd also want to make the local copy reactive:
See on Vue SFC Playground
const localPosts = reactive(props.posts.map((post) => {
    return {
        ...post,
        data: {...post.data, label: 'new value here'},
    };
}));


There is a property on each post called data I need to add a label to data

@panthro updated the answer

I get map is not a function, probably because posts is not an array.

@panthro yes, find the array in posts or you can add your posts structure's picture  (from the developer console) into the question

Using Watch function to make sure posts has a value.
watch(()=>props.posts,val=>{
    val?.data && val.data.map(post => {
        post.label= 'new value here'
    })
})

